# How can I rearrange 9 column into 3 in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, reshape

I have a data.frame x, with 10 variables whose values are arranged by columns as a,b,c,d,b,c,d,b,c,d. How can I arrange the columns to make it only a,b,c,d?

I have one solution but I am looking for a simpler way.

```
    library(tidyverse)
    A <- rep(x$A, each = 3)
    B <- x %>% select(2,5,8) %>% unlist
    C <- x %>% select(3,6,9) %>% unlist
    D <- x %>% select(4,7,10) %>% unlist
    df <- data.frame(A, B, C, D)
```

Is there another way?

Comment: data.frame column names can't be duplicated.  Do you have a `matrix`?

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. i.e. `x` is not defined.  May be you need `sapply(split.default(x, sub("\\.?\\d+", "", names(x))), unlist)`

Comment: This sounds like something you could do with the melt command from the reshape package: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v021i12

Comment: l = rnorm(10)
m = rnorm(10)
n = rnorm(10)
o = rnorm(10)
p = rnorm(10)
q = rnorm(10)
r = rnorm(10)
s = rnorm(10)
t = rnorm(10)
u = rnorm(10)
x <- data.frame(l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u)

Comment: There are 10 columns in your data. How do you divide them into 4 columns? What is the logic to reduce them?

Comment: Question is not clear. Are you trying to retain unique letters and remove the duplicated ones? Check out [`distinct()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/distinct.html) or [`unique()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/unique). 

You can try pasting the output of `dput(x, control = NULL)` so we can better answer your question